# tstools - connect a multicast stream as input?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, multicast

All the examples I've found for this are for reading files, not a multicast stream.  For example, the TSTOOLS user guide gives the example

**tsreport CharliesAngels.ts -v -max 20**

Can tstools read directly from a multicast stream?  E.g.,

**tsreport : -max 100**
for the first 100 packets.

I think I'm getting close with something like the line below,

**tsreport 255.1.1.1:1234 -stdin -max 100**

at least it's not bombing, but it's also just telling me it read the first 100 packets, but gives no other information.  Adding -v (verbose) doesn't help.

tsinfo might also be appropriate for our needs.

I have ffmpeg available, but given that I know it's messing up the particular track I'm interested in for recording, I'd like to work with the tstools suite.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Both `tsreport` and `tsinfo` work with either files or `stdin`. They won't connect to a socket. If you want to use `tstools` you need to capture the multicast MPEG-TS stream to a file first, eg. by using Wireshark with the [mpeg_dump.lua](https://wiki.wireshark.org/mpeg_dump.lua) extension.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
cvlc -q  rtp://1.2.3.4@225.2.3.4:1234 --sout '#std{mux=ts,access=file,dst=-}' | tsinfo -stdin
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.